# Why those big spots appear on my mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, objects, edit-mode

I don't know but whenever I go in edit mode those spots appear all over my mesh. Plesase explain me why it is happening and how can I get rid of it.[image]

[image]

[image]stack.imgur.com/Ut9Q2.jpg

[image]

[image]

Comment: what spots are you talking about? which image? Orange lines?

Comment: Aaah first two pictures, you are talking about those spots... It is because you have solidify modifier and your modifier becames invisible in edit mode... Because of this you can see what is normally covered by modifier... It is Z-clipping,(or sort of)... to remove it just move some vertices in those parts little higher out of donut mesh or just don't look at it.. it is nothing wrong in this case

Comment: yes, about first two images, thanks! I got it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there are essentially two meshes in almost the same place, one the original doughnut mash, and the other one the virtual mesh created by the subdivision surface modifier that will show in the final render. You can turn off “show in edit mode“ on the modifier to hide this virtual geometry while in edit mode, and potentially make your editing experience easier.